# SpringBoot upgrade issue - HibernateValidator has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am getting the following error after upgrading the library **spring-boot-starter-validation** to the version 3.0.1. It is possible to force the application to use the hibernate-validator version 6.* instead of 8.*?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties     ' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Init     ialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/validator/HibernateValidator has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator])
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowi     reCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowire     CapableBeanFactory.java:481)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBean     Registry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java     :211)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListable     BeanFactory.java:1134)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBe     anFactory.java:1062)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolv     er.java:835)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.ja     va:741)
            ... 77 more
```

Follow below my configuration:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not on hibernate-validator, but on the jdk you are using. You are still using Java 8 ("Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0") and that the Hibernate dependency requires Java 11 ("class file version 55.0"). Moreover, [Spring Boot 3 requires Java 17](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0) so even if you are able to use a previous version of hibernate-validator many other issues like this one will pop out. You should first upgrade to Java 17.